# Operation on each possible pair of items in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I want to collect the values of the product of each pair in a list of numbers.

This works fine with smaller numbers, but not with larger ones. How can I optimize my solution?

```
#will work fine with min = 10 & max = 99
#but not with these values under
min = 1000
max = 9999
seq = range(min, max + 1)
products = set()
for i in seq:
    for j in seq:
        p = i * j
        products.add(p)
```

Comment: One optimization is to change `for j in seq` to `for j in range(i, max+1)`. That's because multiplication is commutative. For example, `2 * 3` is equal to `3 * 2`, so there's no reason to try `i=3, j=2` because you will have already tried `i=2, j=3`.

Comment: you could set the initial size (n*(m-n) is a generous upper bound (should be much lower, because of collisions)) of the set to avoid the need of internal growth.

Comment: The real problem is that there are about 21 million unique products, out of the 40 million possible products. So you're building a really big `set`, regardless of how you do it.

Comment: Do you want a list of *unique product values*, or a list of *products of all unique pairs*? The latter will obviously contain duplicate values since e.g. `1000 * 4000` equals `2000 * 2000`. Your question description suggests you want the latter, but your code suggests you want the former (since it creates a `set`). So which is it?

Comment: What does "work fine" mean in your question? There are something like 40 million unique pairs. I don't know how big your `product` is, but even if it's moderate size you're talking a couple gigabytes of memory. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Re *"This works fine with smaller numbers, but not with larger ones"*: In what way? What happens?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) to take the outer product and then take the unique values.

```
min_num = 1000
max_num = 9999

numbers = np.arange(min_num, max_num+1)

products = np.unique(np.outer(numbers, numbers))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a set directly with a comprehension.  To optimize, only compute each product once by multiplying numbers with subsequent ones and themselves rather than every inverted pairs (which only wastes time producing duplicate values):

```
lo = 1000
hi = 9999

prods = {i*j for i in range(lo,hi+1) for j in range(i,hi+1)}

print(len(prods)) # 20789643
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested list comprehension should be faster:

```
products = [i*j for i in seq for j in seq]
```